# ldapsearch - Format output to group by user

Tags: unix, sed, grep, formatting, ldap

I have an ldapsearch query such as:

`ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b dc=level1,dc=level2,dc=level3 '(userid=123)' userid,email1,email2,email3`

This returns the following for user123:

```
mail1: something1@test.com
mail2: something2@test.com
mail3: something3@test.com
userid: 123
```

The issue is, I will not be doing this only for user123 -- I will be doing it for hundreds of thousands of users. Ideally, I would like the output to be something like this, one line per user:

```
123,something1@test.com,something2@test.com,something3@test.com
456,else1@test.com
789,other1@test.com,other2@test.com
...
```

Or even better, this:

```
123,something1@test.com
123,something2@test.com
123,something3@test.com
456,else1@test.com
789,other1@test.com
789,other2@test.com
...
```

Note that users can have different number of email addresses. Is there a way to achieve this formatting? Right now, I have something like this:

`ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b dc=level1,dc=level2,dc=level3 '(userid=123)' userid,email1,email2,email3 | grep -E '^userid:*|^mail1:*|^mail2:*|^mail3:*' | sed 's/^ *//' | awk '!seen[$0]++'`

For user123, this gets me:

```
something1@test.com
something2@test.com
something3@test.com
123
```

But if I add `| paste -sd ','`, it would concatenate the results for all 100k+ users. I would like to have one line per user.

Comment: Do all users have at most 3 email attributes? Where will the userids be coming from? Does it have to be `ldapsearch`?

Comment: Yes, I am using ldapsearch. Users can have any amount of email attributes.

Comment: Attributes in ldapsearch output might not be sorted as you expect (uid, then mail), it could be for one entry, but not for another one (mail, mail1, uid). You probably need to use an ldap client (@see python-ldap).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of output is not possible with ldap command alone.
Need to redirect the output of ldap command to a file and then have a java/shell/python script to read the file and reformat, as needed.